# scrapy response.xpath returns empty array on xml document with default namespace, while response.re works

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy, default-namespace

I am new to scrappy and I was playing with the scrapy shell trying to crawl this site: [www.spiegel.de/sitemap.xml](http://www.spiegel.de/sitemap.xml)

I did it with

```
scrapy shell "http://www.spiegel.de/sitemap.xml"
```

and it works all fine, when i use

```
response.body
```

i can see the whole page including xml tags

however for instance this:

```
response.xpath('//loc')
```

simply wont work.

The result i get is an empty array

while

```
response.selector.re('somevalidregexpexpression')
```

would work

any idea what could be the reason? could be related to encoding or so? the site is not utf-8

I am using python 2.7 on Win 7. I tried the xpath() on another site (dmoz) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem was due to the *default namespace* declared at the root element of the XML :

```
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
```

So in that XML, the root element and its descendants without prefix inherits the same namespace, *implicitly*.

On the other hand, in XPath, you need to use prefix that bound to a namespace URI to reference element in that namespace, there is no such *default namespace* implied.

You can use [`selector.register_namespace()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.register_namespace) to bind a namespace prefix to the default namespace URI, and then use the prefix in your XPath :

```
response.selector.register_namespace('d', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')
response.xpath('//d:loc')
```

Comment: @har07 you absolute life saver!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use xpath with local namespace such as in:

```
response.xpath("//*[local-name()='loc']")
```

This is especially useful if you are parsing responses from multiple heterogeneous sources and you don't want to register each and every namespace.